# Dapr Service Invocation Connection Refused issue

Tags: asp.net-core, docker-compose, dapr

I have a ASP.Net core Razor app that calls an api called TokenAPI, as well as another API called DevOps that calls the Token API, using the Service Invocation block. All of these are hosted in DAPR.
The web app and 2 APIs are hosted locally with Docker Compose. The web app can sucessfully call the Token API using the service invocation block, but the DevOps API fails with
"Exception":"System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused (127.0.0.1:3500)"

I am at a loss as to why this is not working and have been comparing the configuration in my docker-compose file, but cannot figure out why the web-to-api works, whilst the api-to-api fails. Both the Web App and DevOps api uses the same code and config used to call the Token API when creating calling CreateInvokeHttpClient during app startup. So, with code being te same, the only place I can think of, must be the docker-compose:

```
cas.tokens.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80;https://+:443
    ports:
      - "5105:80"
      - "5115:443"
      - "50005:50001"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  cas.devops.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80;https://+:443
    ports:
      - "5106:80"
      - "5116:443"
      - "50006:50001"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  cas.web:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "5111:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
    networks:
      - mynetwork      
castokensapi-dapr:
        command: ["./daprd",
          "-app-id", "tokensapi",
          "-app-port", "80", --enable-api-logging,
          "-dapr-http-port", "3605",
          "-placement-host-address", "dapr-placement:50000",
          "-components-path", "/components",
          "-config", "/configuration/config.yaml"
          ]
        volumes:
          - "./dapr/components/:/components"
          - "./dapr/configuration/:/configuration"
    
      casdevopsapi-dapr:
        command: ["./daprd",
          "-app-id", "devopsapi",
          "-app-port", "80", --enable-api-logging,
          "-dapr-http-port", "3606",
          "-placement-host-address", "dapr-placement:50000",
          "-components-path", "/components",
          "-config", "/configuration/config.yaml"
          ]
        volumes:
          - "./dapr/components/:/components"
          - "./dapr/configuration/:/configuration"
    
      casweb-dapr:
        command: [
          "./daprd",
         "-app-id", "casweb", --enable-api-logging,
         "-placement-host-address", "dapr-placement:50000",
         "-components-path", "/components",
          "-config", "/configuration/config.yaml"
        ]
        volumes:
          - "./dapr/components/:/components"
          - "./dapr/configuration/:/configuration"
```

I am confused as to why DAPR resolves the endpoint to be 127.0.0.1:3500 instead of 127.0.0.1:3605, as per the config?

Below is a screenshot of what the app-id resolves for both service invocations from web-to-api to api-to-api.

[image: Dapr HTTP Client]

The issue seems to be that the service location is either not working or, there is something more fundamental that I misunderstand.

Any help is much appreciated

[UPDATE]
I managed to get this to work, but not entirely sure why yet lol. Removing the "-dapr-http-port" fixes this issue, but I would still like to know why.
Will post here when I know more.

-Mike

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `-dapr-http-port` means that the service will use the default http port which is 3500 allowing dapr to resolve the endpoint as it connects to 127.0.0.1:3500 hence allowing the system to work.

In order to use a different http port, you have to add an additional environment variable to the app itself, `DAPR_HTTP_PORT`. This should be set to the same value as the http port on the sidecar - this is usually handled by dapr when running locally with dapr run or in kubernetes with the sidecar-injector but is a manual process when running in a container in this way.